# Is "warn from" grammatically wrong?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

SENTENCE: "The ministry of health warns from the consumption of melon fruits"

My colleagues and I are debating whether or not "warns from" is grammatically correct. I googled the phrase and although, "warned about", "warned of", and "warned against" popped up, "warns from" never did. But I'm thinking, maybe it's just not colloquially used but still grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

You will find that language changes. There are constructions which are possible from a **rules** base but may not be used since people do not think in rules when they talk.   Not sure what the technical term is for this.

And then there are often used expressions which fall *outside the rules* that are often used and these are sometimes called *idioms*.

What is important is to be *understood*.

Your phrase

> **warns from**

is not used, or if it is would be considered to be nonnative, eventhough it is understandable.

> **warns about**
>   **warns against**

would be better.

> The ministry of health warns **about** the consumption of melon fruits

Comment: I agree with everything about this answer except the possible implication that **warned about** is the best choice. It is far better than **warned from**, but **warned against** is better still.

Comment: @JeffMorrow +1 I did only use "***better***" not "***best***", your suggestion has been added.

Comment: I actually noted the use of the comparative.. That is why I said "possible implication." I should have said "possible inference." My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Saying what preposition goes with what verb and with what meaning is not a matter of grammar, but of usage. At least in the US, **warn against** is both idiomatic and clear when the intended meaning of **warn** is to **advise against.** And **against** is almost certainly the clearest choice for the intended meaning of the sentence that you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

It is idiomatic to be **warned from** or **warned off**.

However, *in contemporary English*, we are normally warned off or warned from {a place or particular path}, that is, told to stay away from it because of some danger or some other set of malign or unprofitable  circumstances.

We might be **warned from** *a poisoned well*.  A ship might be **warned off** *a sandbank*. We might be **warned from** *a particular career*. The warning is an attempt to avert us from a literal or figurative path.

But we are not normally **warned off eating** or **warned from eating** melons.

Rather, we are **advised|warned against eating** fish high in mercury, or we are  or  **warned not to eat** fish high in mercury.

We can be **steered from eating** fish high in mercury.